# How to get sound card back after fixing mute below threshold issue?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I was having [USB audio mutes below 35 %](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511250/volume-mutes-when-set-below-20-14-04) issue. So I followed the instructions at over [here](https://chrisjean.com/fix-for-usb-audio-is-too-loud-and-mutes-at-low-volume-in-ubuntu/) to fix it. And it worked. But now internal speakers don't work anymore.

```
user@hp-elitedesk:~$ pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

On the other hand PulseAudio does detect the card:

```
user@hp-elitedesk:~$ pactl list short cards 0   
alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00    module-alsa-card.c 1    
alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3  module-alsa-card.c
```

Doing `sudo alsa force-reload` didn't work. What can do to get my internal speakers working again?

It seems its not the first time someones internal speakers stopped working after following Chris Jean's post. I found another user on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735718/usb-headphones-get-muted-when-setting-volume-below-a-certain-threshold?rq=1#comment1473945_804368) for whom the same thing happened. ALSA seems to be detecting the card as well.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I checked the output of `pacmd dump` and saw this:

```
### Configuration dump generated at Fri Oct  5 14:16:21 2018

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore
load-module module-augment-properties
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-udev-detect
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="1" name="usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-alsa-card device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
load-module module-bluetooth-policy
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
load-module module-bluez5-discover
load-module module-native-protocol-unix
load-module module-default-device-restore
load-module module-rescue-streams
load-module module-always-sink
load-module module-intended-roles
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
load-module module-console-kit
load-module module-systemd-login
load-module module-position-event-sounds
load-module module-role-cork
load-module module-filter-heuristics
load-module module-filter-apply
load-module module-cli-protocol-unix

set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo 0x7f79
set-sink-mute alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo no
suspend-sink alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo no

set-source-volume alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo.monitor 0x10000
set-source-mute alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo.monitor no
suspend-source alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo.monitor no
set-source-volume alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-mono 0x66a9
set-source-mute alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-mono no
suspend-source alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-mono yes

set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-mono
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 off

set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-stereo
set-default-source alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Microsoft_LifeChat_LX-3000-00.analog-mono

### EOF
```

So clearly the `set-card-profile` command is the issue because its not loading a profile. So then I hunted for the profile definition in the output of `pactl list` and then ran:

```
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

This fixed the problem and brought the sink bank. But I don't want to run this each time after I boot. Is there a work around? I realized something must be going wrong when pulseaudio is loading up. Hence, I ran it from terminal:

```
user@hp-elitedesk:i3$ pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: [/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common:129] Invalid value for volume-limit
E: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: [/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common:129] Invalid value for volume-limit
E: [pulseaudio] alsa-mixer.c: [/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common:129] Invalid value for volume-limit
```

So the suggested edit of adding `volume-limit` in Chris Jean's post is causing an issue. I removed the line, and then there was no problem. On the other removing that line caused the audio mute below 35% to reappear.

Does anyone know of a fix/workaround? It looks like if I want to fix the audio mute issue, then I will need to add that command to some startup script.